# How to properly build a list of divs dynamically (Error)

Tags: html, .net

I'm working on a .NET Web API application and am having an odd issue. I have two separate functions to populate some divs with data from my API. I build up a list of entries in a string and then append the html to pre-defined divs.

The first time I do this it works fine, like so:

[image: Working code]

I do this again for another data set, like so:

[image: Broken code]

I'm fairly certain I've got the divs defined in the same way, and I've kept looking over to make sure that I'm closing all my tags properly. Yet for some reason, Visual Studio yells at me and throws this error:

[image: Parser Error]

Is there something glaringly obvious that's wrong with my code? For my information, both are in a block of @if-else using the Razor engine, and the script inside this block is surrounded by a text tag. This has worked for me everywhere I'm used it, which is why this error is so confusing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have too much experience with this, but why are there two closing div tags in a row on the line in question (line 100)?

Comment: That final div close tag ends the div row which is defined on line 94 (the second picture in my post)

Comment: I see. Sorry, I missed one of the opening tags when I was looking through the list. I thought I had an easy answer... I should have known better... too easy.

Comment: Line 94 - is that supposed to be `=` or `+=`

Comment: Above this section businessdevs is defined as a variable, but that is the first place that I store anything in it, so it could be either one, I just chose = to mark that as the location where it is being added to first. This also lets me loop through a list of results and reuse the variable.

Comment: Ok. just saw it was different from the first - wasn't sure you meant to assign it.

Comment: Line 98 - you forgot a closing `>` on the div tag.

Comment: I knew I was missing something small. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. I've had the same problem before... A fresh set of eyes can make a huge difference.